# Blocking font download

Tags: browser, fonts, http, css

For some reason, certain fonts look terrible on my computer—some lines are double-thick, splotches of 'ink', etc. They're hardly readable, and certainly not showing up as intended. Here's an example of a font as designed:

[image: Original Font]

and as displayed on my screen:

[image: My view of it]

(sorry for not having a better example at hand).

On one hand it would be nice to diagnose the problem itself. (Vista machine, problem happens in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE, etc.) but I think a more practical stopgap solution would be to block the download of the webfonts. Is there a way to do this?

I don't really care at what point this happens: stopping certain @-rules in CSS, disallowing the display of custom fonts, blocking it on a TCP or HTTP level. I don't want to do a DNS block on fonts.googleapis.com and themes.googleusercontent.com since that would stop unrelated good stuff as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could block it on a http-level if you have a proxy server. Then you should be able to tell it to block the Content-Type that is associated with the font. Now I don't know the content-type, but it should be easy enough to find using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

On another slightly related note. I have one font that behaves like that on my computer. It's caused by a bug in the font and Clear Type in Windows. If I turn of clear type the font looks good. Or as good a font looks without clear type. So perhaps you could try that first?

I've checked and you might be able to block the fonts using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). By changing the custom rules you might be able to do it. It could be useful just to see if it would work. Try adding this code to the CustomRules.js in the OnBeforeResponse function.

```
if(oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "font/woff")) {
            oSession.oRequest.FailSession(404, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked font file");
}
```

Comment: I agree, it looks very much like the issues I had with ClearType. But it's already off, so that's not it.

Comment: The Content-Type is `font/woff` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this requirement today, as Google seems to have started rolling out "Google Sans" to search result headings. In my case, the font is (I assume) displaying as intended, but trying to read text in that particular font as opposed to something traditional like Arial is absolutely doing my head in.

I could theoretically use a CSS user style, but this approach would mean writing an override for every rule that references the font, and keeping it updated whenever the site's CSS changes. (In addition, in Google's case, a lot of their class names and the like seem randomised - possibly a side-effect of a minifier or similar, as opposed to a deliberate choice, but definitely feels very anti-accessibility.)

In any case, with a bit of effort, I was able to write a GreaseMonkey script to do the job:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Block Fonts
// @namespace   mynamespace
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
function BlockFonts(blockedFonts) {
    var blockFont = {};
    for (var i in blockedFonts)
    {
        blockFont[blockedFonts[i]] = true;
    }
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i in sheets) {
        try {
            var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
            for (var r in rules) {
                if (rules[r].style && rules[r].style.fontFamily)
                {
                    var items = rules[r].style.fontFamily.split(',');
                    var newItems = [];
                    for (var n in items)
                    {
                        var font = items[n].replaceAll('"', '');
                        if (font in blockFont)
                        {
                            console.log('Blocked "'+font+'"');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newItems.push(items[n]);
                        }
                    }
                    rules[r].style.fontFamily = newItems.join(',');
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

BlockFonts(['Google Sans']);
```

To customise it to your use case, simply **change `['Google Sans']` at the end to an array with the names of the fonts you want to block** (for example, `['Google Sans', 'Example Font 2']`) - I wrote it to block any number of fonts, even though I only needed one in my use case.

<sub>The try-catch is there on a per-sheet basis as I was getting a "SecurityError" for some sheets when just executing this in the console, which was preventing future sheets from being scanned. It doesn't happen when running as a GreaseMonkey script (at time of writing at least) but I figured it was worthwhile keeping it in.</sub>

Tested in Pale Moon 29.1.1 with the [PM GreaseMonkey fork 3.31.4](https://github.com/janekptacijarabaci/greasemonkey/releases/tag/3.31.4Fork).